# Riesz homomorphism (Banach–Stone theorem)

Tags: functional-analysis, abstract-algebra

Let $X,Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces, and consider $$J:C(X)\to C(Y) $$

a bounded linear bijection such that $J(f\cdot g) = J(f)J(g)$.

I know that if $T:C(X)\to C(Y)$ is a linear bijection, being a Riesz homomorphism with $T(1) =1$, then $X$ is homeomorphic with $Y$ (a slightly altered Banach–Stone theorem).

$C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ are Riesz spaces with partial order $f\leq g$ when $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x$. I want to show that the above map $J$ is a Riesz homomorphism, i.e.
$$J(f\vee g) = J(f)\vee J(g),  \ \ \ f,g\in C(X)$$

$f\vee g\in C(X)$ is the map $x\mapsto \max\{f(x),g(x)\} $. From multiplicativity it is clear that $J(1) =1$, and one can see that $J(f\vee g) = J(f+g) = J(f)+J(g) = J(f)\vee J(g) $whenever $f$, and $g$ have disjoint supports. But i have trouble showing this for any $f,g\in C(X)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that any positive $f\in C(X)$ has a unique positive square root, that is, a positive function $g \in C(X)$ such that $g^2 = f$ holds. Now we have $J(f) = J(\sqrt{f}\cdot\sqrt{f}) = J(\sqrt{f})^2$, so it follows that $J(f)$ is also positive. Thus, we see that $J$ is a positive map.

Secondly, let $f\in C(X)$ be positive once again. As positive elements are mapped to positive elements, we see that $J(\sqrt{f})$ positive as well. Hence it follows that $J(\sqrt{f})$ is the unique positive square root of $J(f)$:
$$ \sqrt{J(f)} = J(\sqrt{f}),\qquad\text{for all $f \geq 0$}. $$
Now we have
$$ J\big(\,|f|\,\big) = J\left(\sqrt{f^2}\right) = \sqrt{J(f^2)} = \sqrt{J(f)^2} = \big|\,J(f)\,\big|,\qquad\text{for all $f\in C(X)$}. $$
Recall that this is one of the equivalent criteria for $J$ being a Riesz homomorphism.

Comment: haha, hey boy. Its kind of an old questioin...(had 'm ook opgelost. Koste me wel even tijd om zo'n simpel inzichtje te krijgen. :P)

Comment: Haha, excellent! :P I just stumbled upon this unanswered question while searching for something else completely. :-) I didn't realise we knew each other in real life. :p